# cordova Install Android Targets: Not installed (Using sdkmanager)

Tags: android, cordova, android-sdk-tools

I am on ubuntu 18.04.

I am setting up a `cordova` project. I dont want to install Android Studio so I downloaded sdk tools package. However when I run `cordova requiremets`, I keep getting the out put below.

[View image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPAVQ.png)

[image]

That means I have not installed the android targets yet.

I have tried to look for proper guides on how to install `android target` with sdk tools without installing Android Studio without success. Help on this will be highly appreciated.

(I hope my question is clear, English not so good, for clarification ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally cracked it. What you need to do is:

use `sdkmanager` commands to install platforms and other modules.

Note: `Android` command is deprecated.

First list all remotely available tools.

```
sdkmanager --list
```

From the list you can, for example, install `platforms;android-27`

```
sdkmanager --install "platforms;android-27"
```

When you run `cordova requirements`, now you will find that they are android targets are installed and listed.

Answer (score -1):

That error message tells you what is missing and what you need to do.

You do not have an Android SDK installed on your machine. You either download it with Android Studio or download the SDK separately from here : https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads

Comment: I have installed Android SDK you can see ```Android SDK: installed true```? I downloaded it with separate option. What I wanted to know is how to download the targets. Thanks